# Makefile cant find libraries

Tags: makefile, paho

I'm trying to write my own `makefile` for a `paho.mqtt` project on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I've downloaded & tested the `paho.mqtt` install and its all working as expected.

So I'm now testing some C code but I just cant figure out the `makefile` (I'm new to this), my file so far,

```
NAME = mqtt_test
OBJ = $(NAME).o
LIBS = -libpaho-mqtt3c -libpaho-mqtt3cs
CFLAGS = -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
CC = gcc
EXTENSION = .c

all: $(NAME)

%.o: %$(EXTENSION) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @rm -f *.o *~ core $(NAME)
```

This returns,

```
gcc -o mqtt_test mqtt_test.o -Wall -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -libpaho-mqtt3c -libpaho-mqtt3cs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpaho-mqtt3c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpaho-mqtt3cs
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:14: mqtt_test] Error 1
```

I've checked & the includes and libraries are in the directories I put after the`-I` and `-L` flags.

When I look in `/usr/bin` there is no `ld` but there are `paho` files prefixed with `paho_` but no library files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `-libpaho-mqtt3c` (etc.)

The option is `-l` so when you write `-libpaho-mqtt3c` the linker is looking for libraries named `ibpaho-mqtt3c` which of course do not exist: that would be either `libibpaho-mqtt3c.a` or `libibpaho-mqtt3c.so`.

You want to use `-lpaho-mqtt3c`: remove the `lib` at the front and the extension `.a` or `.so`, and add in the option `-l`.

Comment: And, of course, this is not specific to either makefile or paho, the two tags on the post.

Comment: Ahh I get it now, would compiler flags be a better tag?